# Factory.next not working in FactoryGirl 4.x and Rails 3.0. Anyone know the replacement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I'm very new to Rails and am following along in the Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial book by Michael Hartl and am running into a little bump while using the factory_girl gem.

Specifically, I'm not sure how to update the code

```
Factory.next(...)
```

Before coming to this, I did run into a little problem between the older version of FactoryGirl used in the book and the current 4.1 version I'm using now, but was able to resolve it.

Specifically, the old way of writing code as

> user = Factory(:user)

needed to be updated to

> user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

That was fine, but now I'm coming to the code (as written in the book):

spec/controllers/users_controler_spec.rb

```
.    
@users << Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))
.
```

which I've tried updating to

```
.
@users << FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => FactoryGirl.next(:email))
.
```

but get the error:

```
Failure/Error: @users << FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => FactoryGirl.next(:email))
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `next' for FactoryGirl:Module
```

I've tried a few different variations but still can't quite get it. Is the problem I'm having with FactoryGirl and just not using the gem correctly or does it have something to do with the Ruby methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have to use the method `generate` for sequences:

```
@users << Factory(:user, :email => FactoryGirl.generate(:email))
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage) on sequences and associations for details.

Comment: Great! That seemed to do it! My updated code now looks like `@users << FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => FactoryGirl.generate(:email))` Thank you very much!